# Mixing polar and non polar substances

Tags: solutions

According to the theory of London dispersion forces, intermolecular forces are created in non polar substances by induction of instantaneous dipole to neighbouring molecules. If that is the case then when we mix water and oil, water being polar should induce polarity in oil and they should mix. But they don't. Doesn't water induce polarity to oil? Do I have a false concept or something.

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2734/why-water-cant-mix-with-oil-or-cooking-oil. The short version is: `Water is so strongly attracted to itself that it excludes the oil.`

Comment: My question is that why polarity is not induced in oil

Comment: Water molecules do induce some polarity on the oil molecules when they meet, but the resulting interaction is still significantly weaker than mutual hydrogen bonding between water molecules, so the materials still separate phase almost completely.

Answer (score 0):

Water is already very 'happy' with his own guys due to strong hydrogen bonds . While van der waals force is so weak that its presence is so little for it to be seen while there is hydrogen bond. So even though there is some dipole induced it isn't enough.

> the total energy is lower than when they are mixed. The system is more stable if unmixed. -Chin Yeh